# NavUtils.NavigateUpFromSameTask in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is the host activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "CrimePagerActivity")]
[MetaData("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY", Value = "CriminalIntent.CrimeListActivity")]
public class CrimePagerActivity : FragmentActivity
```

This is the fragment hosted by CrimePagerActivity:

```
public class CrimeFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
```

and

```
try
{
    if (NavUtils.ParentActivity != null)
        NavUtils.NavigateUpFromSameTask(Activity);
}
```

then get an error message:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type **CriminalIntent.CrimePagerActivity** from native handle f3a00019

**Compile using Android version**: API Level 21
**References**:Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 , Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

---

**Update 1**

```html
{System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type CriminalIntent.CrimePagerActivity from native handle 37700019 
---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for CriminalIntent.CrimePagerActivity::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) 
---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
Java.Lang.Error: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Error' was thrown.

  
--- End of managed exception stack trace 
---
java.lang.Error: Java callstack:

 at criminalintent.CrimeFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)

 at criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(CrimeFragment.java:56)

 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1894)

 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2034)

 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:356)
  at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:181)

 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)

 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)

 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)


  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00039] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:267
 
  at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x001ea] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:249
 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x0022b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:255
 
  at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x000ba] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:333
 
  at Java.Lang.Object._GetObject[FragmentActivity] (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:313
 
  at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[FragmentActivity] (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:305
 
  at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.get_Activity () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 
  at CriminalIntent.CrimeFragment.OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item) [0x0002c] in d:\Xamarin Project\TheBigNerdRanchGuide\CriminalIntent\CrimeFragment.cs:115 }
```

After add two constructors:

```
    public CrimePagerActivity()
    {

    }

    public CrimePagerActivity(System.IntPtr i, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership p)
    {

    }
```

**Update 2**

```html
{Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException' was thrown.

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1457 
  at Android.Support.V4.App.NavUtils.NavigateUpFromSameTask (Android.App.Activity sourceActivity) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 
  at CriminalIntent.CrimeFragment.OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item) [0x0008b] in d:\GitHub\Xamarin.Android\App\TheBigNerdRanchGuide\CriminalIntent\CrimeFragment.cs:200
 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity CrimePagerActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)

 at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:178)

 at criminalintent.CrimeFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)

 at criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(CrimeFragment.java:83)

 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1894)

 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2034)

 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:356)

 at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:181)

 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)

 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)

 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
}
```

Comment: Try with the full stack trace.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thank you, I update the question. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try adding the constructor it is saying is missing.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I've tried that, still got exception. {Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException' was thrown.
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1457 
 
...

Comment: Again, provide the full stack trace.

Comment: So again there is a nice indicator of what is wrong: `CrimePagerActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)`. The name of the activity you are providing it is probably wrong or the package name is incorrect. You can check what the resulting name is by looking in the AndroidManifest which is generated and put into the `obj\Android` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice indicator of what is wrong: `CrimePagerActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)`.

The name of the activity you are providing it is probably wrong or the package name is incorrect. You can check what the resulting name is by looking in the AndroidManifest which is generated and put into the `obj\Android` folder.

But the problem in this case is most likely that you are using uppercase for your package name, which Android does not like. If you look in your stack trace it refers to stuff in your app as `criminalintent.xxx` where `xxx` is your fragments or activities.

So instead of writing `Value = "CriminalIntent.CrimeListActivity"` it should be more like `Value = "criminalintent.CrimeListActivity"`. But you can see that in your manifest.

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Android changes my project name to lowercase. I change the `CriminalIntent` to `criminalintent`, it does work. Thank you very much.